# What is the use case of QEMU chardev pty

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, qemu, devices

I'm new to QEMU and playing around with its `chardev`s. I faced the option called `-chardev pty,id=id`. So I tried to create a VM with `-chardev pty,id=pty0` and got the message.

```
char device redirected to /dev/pts/9 (label pty0)
```

So I tried to send some data to it:

```
root@super-pc:~# cat /dev/pts/9
```

and didn't see any output.

What is the use case of this chardev?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but for folks who find there way here via google:

Setting up a chardev by itself isn't particularly useful, but if you associate it with a serial device...

```
-chardev pty,id=char0 -serial chardev=char0
```

...then you have set up a virtual serial port that connects a serial device in your virtual machine to the corresponding pty device on the host.

For example, if I boot a Linux virtual machine like this:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -smp 1 -m 1024 \
  -drive if=virtio,format=qcow2,file=fedora.cow \
  -netdev user,id=net0 \
  -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net0 \
  -serial mon:stdio \
  -chardev pty,id=char0 \
  -serial chardev:char0
```

Then inside the virtual machine, `/dev/ttyS0` is the serial console, and `/dev/ttyS1` is connected to the PTY device created by the `-chardev pty` option. Assuming that when booting the virtual machine I see:

```
char device redirected to /dev/pts/9 (label char0)
```

Then on the host I can connect a serial communication program to `/dev/pts/9`:

```
$ picocom /dev/pts/9
```

And inside the virtual machine, if I run:

```
echo hello world > /dev/ttyS1
```

I will in the output from `picocom`:

```
hello world
```

If I start up a shell on `/dev/ttyS1` inside the virtual machine:

```
bash < /dev/ttyS1 > /dev/ttyS1 2> /dev/ttyS1
```

Then I can interact with that shell over `/dev/pts/9` on the host.